# Two of my questions randomly downvoted at the same time

Tags: discussion

On SF, two of my questions (selected randomly seemingly) were downvoted at the exact same time.
Sounds like some kind of abuse - just out of luck, or does it need to be reported?

Comment: Can you link to the questions?

Comment: There's a [vote abuse algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120595/does-the-vote-abuse-algorithm-roll-back-valid-votes) that should detect "abuse", but nobody knows the votes/time ratio required to trigger it.

Comment: Gotta take the ying with the yang I'm afraid ;)

Comment: I wouldn't class it as abuse based on two votes. Its entirely possible for someone to click on a question you've answered, dowvote your question and follow your username to another question you're both interested in and do the same there, because they genuinely and reasonably believe the answers both deserved a downvote. Its also possible for them to do the same and upvote. Neither is abuse of the voting system and you've got to take the rough with the smooth.

Comment: These two I'm guessing? http://serverfault.com/questions/183879/linux-64b-dangerous-kernel-exploit http://serverfault.com/questions/190840/mount-a-ext4-partition-on-mac-os-x Edit: Just noticed John linked to these in his answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the two questions are [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/183879/9278) and [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/190840/9278). Sorry, they really are quite poor questions.

The first includes this contradictory line:

> Or, since it seems only a local user may gain root access, standalone servers are pretty safe?

The second includes this one:

> Please describe the procedure - risk free - thanks.

To me both those lines are like fingernails on a blackboard. Although I'm not the one who cast the downvotes, had I see either of those questions during my normal browsing of SF I may well have downvoted them.

Comment: Hmm I must agree the wording makes the sentence unclear (the 1st one meaning was that the hack possible only after log in). But, two old questions downvoted within a minute sounded suspicious to me. It was less for -4 (just lost 100 in a bounty) than to alert SF about a possible random downvoter around.

Comment: @ring0, sometimes when reading someone's post I might look to see what else they've written. Perhaps that's what happened here.

Comment: Guys, if it seems 'somewhat' unclear but you're not entirely convinced that someone else won't make perfect sense of it then why not just IGNORE the question instead of downvoting. As you can see he got perfectly good answers and the question was actually upvoted???

Answer (score 3):

Two downvotes are nothing. Don't take them personally.

If there is *real* abuse, there is an automated system in place that reverses voting irregularities.

Comment: ...that's what I'd expect the person who downvoted him to say...hmm...

Comment: I've downvoted a lot, including this meta question, but I'm not the cause of this post. Sorry for the disappointment.

Comment: ...well, that kind of surprised me as a response.

Comment: I'm not taking it personnaly, and this is not a big deal. However I respect the work of others, where it's sincere and justified ; and I'm  expecting the same. These 2 downvotes are obviously an abuse. It's not the number of points, it's the intention. I have some consideration for the SE sites, where most questions and answers show a high level of competency ; such instinctual and childish behavior should be discouraged. At least, the guy could have downvoted twice in a week, and i wouldn't have noticed...

Comment: Why is two downvotes abuse? First of all, there are thousands of users. Coincidence happens. Assuming coincidence is ruled out, the user could have read your profile, looked through, found two things worthy of a DV and downvoted. That's hardly abuse.

Comment: In fact, I just looked at your profile and there are multiple things that I'd consider worthy of a downvote and a close vote, but given the circumstances *that* would be abuse, so I left them be.

Comment: Maybe there were also things you could have upvoted?

Comment: Sure, but your question is complaining about being downvoted. I'm simply saying that I can see why that happened and don't disagree, that's all.

Comment: #MDMarra I think you're missing the point. From the brief time that I've spent in Meta.SF I've noticed a lot of people with these concerns myself included. And generally speaking, when a lot of people have the same concern one should assume there might actually be a valid reason? StackOverflow doesn't seem to suffer from downvoting?